# guest access to samba shares on 10.8

Tags: macos, sharing, file-sharing, smb

Is there any way to allow public (ie no user/password prompt) access to samba shares using the mountain lion built in server?

Even with Everyone set to read/write in System Preferences and the guest account enabled for sharing a password is always required when trying to connect from a windows computer (I've tried both 7 and xp).

Answer (score 6):

Yep!

- Go to 'Users & Groups' in System Preferences
- Select the 'Guest User'
- Tick 'Allow guests to connect to shared folders'

Done :)

Comment: no effect for me though.

Comment: Same for me. And the OP wrote that he tried this option, and that it didn't work.

Comment: Hm, I've managed to reproduce this also. Try user: guest with no password. This works for me. You could script the drive mapping with the user 'guest' with no pass, or use the GUI to 'reconnect at login' with those credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I've got issue to access from OSX to samba server in guest mode.
(probably due to French "invite" instead of guest).

I fix my samba conf to map any bad user to guest.
I hope that can help you.

```
[Global]
...  
 map to guest = bad user
```

---

```
 ✘ MbPro ~ smbutil view -g //wizz
smbutil: server rejected the authentication: Authentication error
 ✘ MbPro ~ smbutil view -g //wizz
Share                                           Type    Comments
-------------------------------
public                                          Disk    LinusPublic
IPC$                                            Pipe    IPC Service (Samba)
```